# Interesting Tags in Individual question page

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Hello All,

Sometimes when i was browsing through the tags and start reading a question under a specific tag, i wasn't able to directly switch to my other interesting tag as i don't find my interesting tags available on that page.

There can be a panel in the right side that is always visible with my interesting tags which will be easier to navigate.

[alt text http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/3285/interestingg.jpg](http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/3285/interestingg.jpg)

Comment: That's a horrible image. I can't even see any freehand circles.

Comment: To cover the whole page i have reduced the font size. Yet I am sure the text would have explained all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following options:

- Open up questions in tabs
- Click Back on your browser
- Alt + ⇦

You're asking for more elements to fill out your screen for the sake of saving yourself some simple actions. Why do you want more clutter on your screen?

Comment: Clutter is cool. Just have everything on the same screen! That's the way it's done.